# Running Oracle For loop in parallel

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, parallel-processing, sql-insert

I have to following sql for an oracle database on AWS RDS

```
BEGIN
 FOR user_id_count IN 1..4000 LOOP
   INSERTUSERINTOFINALTABLE(user_id_count);
 END LOOP;
END;
```

where the INSERTUSERINTOFINALTABLE PROC is defined as follows

```
INSERT INTO FinalTable (USERID,  ABC,  DEF, ...,XYZ )
 select
  a.USERID,
  b.ABC,
  b.DEF,
  ....
  b.XYZ
from a
left outer join b on a.USERID = b.userid
where a.userid = USER_ID and b.XYZ not in ( select XYZ from c);
```

The reason why I am not doing it for all the user as a simple insert int is because my data is really big and wanted to make sure I don't run out of memory.

The question is, is there a way to run this in parallel in oracle?

Thanks

Comment: In theory, you could use DBMS_JOB to create a lot of jobs, but I'm not exactly sure if this is a good idea in your case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in inserting many rows in parallel. I will explain why.

If the `insert` statement is the only statement in your loop, the statements won't really run in parallel. That is because the `insert` statement is atomic.

You can't have two insert statements in the same session, running at the same time, especially when your insert is based on a select statement from another table, which will most likely lock the table for concurrent read actions.

Comment: @Amer: It is very unlikely you will gain anything by running in parallel. Try to optimize your sql and indexes. That might help more.

Comment: My sql is very simple... do you think there is anything I can do to it? any changes that I can do on the source or target tables that could help?

Comment: You tagged it Oracle. Are you targeting MySQL or Oracle? Both have indexes by the way.

Comment: Okay, then I misunderstood. Still, indexes can help a lot in certain circumstances. An index on `b.userid, b.XYZ` would help a lot already.

Comment: Thanks Patrick... my oracle knowledge is very limited... any specific type of index would be useful?